# Woocommerce Change The Price Of A Product Once Woocommerce Has Retreived It From Database

Tags: plugins

In a normal case the Woocommerce retrieves the price from the database and displays it. How can one customize Woocommerce so that when the price of the product is retrieved from the database it is then changed at the very initial stage before it is used anywhere else (for checkout, cart etc).

**Visualization:-**

[image]

**Constraints:-**

The price should not be changed in the database. PHP script should change the price and manage it.

**Progress:-**

I'm not getting any directions in this problem. I believe that I've to modify `class-wc-product-simple.php` at `line:68`

```
       if ( $children_by_price ) {
            foreach ( $children_by_price as $child ) {
                $child_price = get_post_meta( $child, '_price', true ); // that's line 68.
                update_post_meta( $this->get_parent(), '_price', $child_price );
            }
        }
```

so that I can modify the price as it is just retrieved from the database.I know that modifying WooCommerce core is not recommended, but that's okay for me for the time being.

Comment: Technically, this is not really WordPress-specific, but I have a soft spot for WooCommerce, and you put a lot of effort into your question, so I will try to point you in the right direction. See the `WC_Product` abstract class and specifically [`get_price()`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php#L747) method and the `woocommerce_get_price` filter therein.

Comment: Take a look at the WP HTTP API to query that third party data. Then [edit] your quesiton and show us your actual code.

Comment: @helgatheviking Thank you very much for giving directions. I'd fixed the problem and shared the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, got it working with this code:-

```
function return_custom_price($price, $product) {       
        global $post, $woocommerce;
        $post_id = $post->ID;
        if($post_id == '696' || $post_id == '697' || $post_id == '705' /*|| $post_id == '53'*/ || $post_id == ''){
        // cart, checkout, , order recieved, order now
                $post_id = $product->id;
        }
        $new_price = get_post_meta($post_id, '_price', true);
        if($new_price=='') {
            $new_price = $price;
        } else {
            $api_call = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20csv%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Ffinance.yahoo.com%2Fd%2Fquotes.csv%3Fe%3D.csv%26f%3Dc4l1%26s%3DNZD%3DX%2CAUD%3DX%22%3B&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=";
            $data[] = json_decode(file_get_contents($api_call));
            $nzd = (double) $data[0]->query->results->row[0]->col1;
            $aud = (double) $data[0]->query->results->row[1]->col1;
            $new_price = ( $nzd / $aud ) * $new_price;
        }
        return $new_price;         
}      
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'return_custom_price', $product, 2);
```